# Criterion for the linear independence for a family of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

How does one prove the following lemma?

Let $E$ and $F$ two nontrivial vector spaces and let $(u_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of vectors in $E$.
The family $(u_i)_{i \in I}$ is linearly independent iff for every family $(v_i)_{i \in I}$, of vectors in $F$, there exists some linear map $f: E \rightarrow F$ such that $f(u_i) = v_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints: the family is linearly independent if $\sum_i \alpha_i u_i=0$ iff $\alpha_i=0$ for all $i$.

Suppose there exists $f$ such that $f(u_i)=v_i$ and the $v_i$ are linearly independent, what can you say about $f(\sum_i \alpha_i u_i)$?

Now suppose that $u_i$ is linearly independent, simply define $f$ by its action $f(u_i)=v_i$. Is this a well defined linear function?